# test windows rdp credentials use and password

Tags: php, linux, guacamole

I want to make an checker to check RDP IP with user and password

I've tried to install `guacamole server` I install it on ubuntu and it works good and connects well but I can't make any check using php or any coding language with it because its system is so complicated

so if any one have any idea about how to check RDP IP with user and password using any coding please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command line [RDP clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858717/remote-desktop-rdp-credentials-check-from-command-line-no-gui) ([or this one](http://opentechnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/compile-headless-freerdp-credential-checking.html)) for linux if you environment is a Linux (or MacOS), or run [RDP client](https://www.windows-commandline.com/launch-remote-desktop-run-command/#:%7E:text=Just%20open%20Run%20from%20start,to%20open%20and%20press%20enter.) from command line if you using Windows.

`guacamole` is not good idea for automation. You need to run web-side javascript to connect, so [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or [Chrome headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) will be only possible solution as I know.

- **EDIT 1: How to run remote command**

1. Set [SSH passwordless connection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-2) to freerdp server
2. Run [freerdp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266041/how-to-execute-external-shell-commands-from-laravel-controller) on remote server [via SSH connection](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osx-bsd-ssh-run-command-on-remote-machine-server/)

```php
$process = new Process(['ssh', 'user@serverB' 'freerdp ...']);
$process->run();
```

In other way you can create standalone PHP service on serverB which trying to [run local freerdp command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with requested IP (or user?) and returning result

Comment: this tutorial is very good [tutorial](http://opentechnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/compile-headless-freerdp-credential-checking.html) it's worked in linux very well but how can i send requests to the linux server using php laravel to check the rdp credentials as api

Comment: php laravel server and linux server is a same machine?

Comment: no not the same machine the laravel project on server A and i install free rdp on server B i want to execute the commands in the tutorial from Server A to Server B and see the result on Server A using echo or some thing like that

Comment: added info into answer

Comment: sir in the tutorial in the step of cmake which is step 4 i got this error and i can't find any solution https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YNhTKmhVmC/

Comment: you @rzlvmp still here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid that I can't help here. Here is many reasons of compilation errors (also I don't have experience in C programming). And these errors depends on your OS and installed libraries (and it's versions), so I can't reproduce error on my environment. Try to install dependencies if it not installed (`sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev`). Or try to find newer manuals how to build freerdp. https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation . You may use only part `Modify relevant parts of the code` in manual above. Other build processes will be better to check in newer manuals